# ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java

В общем, вопрос в следующем. Нужно из `ByteArrayOutputStream` записать в `ByteArrayInputStream`.
То есть, е считываю данные из файла в `ByteArrayOutputStream`, а потом это все надо записать в другой файл с помощью `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Делаю так

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//считываем данные
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

Так ли я это делаю? или бред какой то?

Comment: Для каких целей - это нужно?

Comment: скачать файл из dropbox и загрузить на амазон, но при этом не сохраняя его локально

Comment: оно в принципе и работает так вроде норм

Comment: Разве у `dropbox`'a` нет API?

Comment: там где написано //считываем данные - там и есть получение файла из друпбокс через апи, и записываем в outputStream

Comment: т.е. вы перекладываете байты из какого-то `InputStream` в `ByteArrayOutputStream`, потом превращаете массив в `ByteArrayInputStream` и пишете байты из него в какой-то `OutputStream`? Почему нельзя сразу писать из входного в выходной потоки?

Comment: @zRrr потому что надо писать из выходного во входной

Comment: вроде понял вашу проблему. В апи Dropbox можно [получить](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/81c01e3d368154a77c88b92f92b7932191b74520/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/DbxDownloader.java#L32) `InputStream` для скачивания файла. Дальше можно попробовать отдать его амазоновскому апи.

Answer (score 1):

Так конечно можно, но проблема в том, что вы сначала по сути все пишете `byte[]`, потом его засовываете в `ByteArrayInputStream` - то есть по сути вместо файловой системы используете оперативную память, которая как известно не бесконечна.

Обычно такое копирование из потока в поток делается через [channels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html).

Если неохота сильно заморачиваться берите Apache Commons - там есть метод [copy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/utils/IOUtils.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-), который копирует из потока в поток через внутренний буфер (размер можно задавать) - реализован через `java.nio.channels`

Comment: Насколько я понял в том методе что вы скинули, от Apache Commons, копирование идет из Input в Output. А мне надо наоборот, из Output в input